# React al guardar al iniciar app no se manda el primer campo

Tags: reactjs, componentes

Estoy teniendo un problema con mi componente formulario, al iniciar la aplicacion y doy en save con los campos vacios, solo me muestra `email`

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-nightingale-1o84d?file=/src/App.js

Reproducir error:

1. Abrir codeSandbox y presionar save
2. Verficar la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Veran que el parametro `name` no llega, pero si agrego valores los manda correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el ejemplo que diste, en `src/components/form.js`, línea 13:

```javascript
updateState({
  ...state,
  ...v
});
```

Reasignalo como:

```javascript
updateState(Object.assign(state, v));
```

MDN Docs: [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)